# Text data to a normal date conversion

Tags: excel

I need to convert some data to a normal date field. I have a column that has the data in the format below.

```
14 Hrs 9 Mins 56 Secs
14 Hrs 14 Mins 31 Secs
14 Hrs 43 Mins 52 Secs
16 Hrs 12 Mins
```

I need to make it a normal date.

Anybody with suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)/24+MID(A1,FIND("Hrs",A1)+4,2)/(24*60)+IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("Mins",A1)+5,2)/(24*60*60),0)
```

Add an additional error trap if whole hours only are a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function TTime(inpt As String) As Date
   Dim I As Long, v As Long, tag As String
   ary = Split(inpt, " ")
   TTime = TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
   For I = 0 To UBound(ary) - 1 Step 2
      v = ary(I)
      tag = ary(I + 1)
      If tag = "Hrs" Then TTime = TTime + TimeSerial(v, 0, 0)
      If tag = "Mins" Then TTime = TTime + TimeSerial(0, v, 0)
      If tag = "Secs" Then TTime = TTime + TimeSerial(0, 0, v)
   Next I
End Function
```

Format the destination cell with a time format:

[image]